# C# script to search through html

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

I am trying to write a code with C# which read an access database that has two fields (User ID, Track ID) line by line and set the each userID in the following url (replace the  tag with userID):

```
http://abcdef.comghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<userid>?groups=<userid>
```

and search through the data which shows on webpage(the data is in JSON format). if the Track ID which is in the same record of User ID shows, the counter increase 1.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Net;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\hidden.accdb";
            conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from hidden.accdb";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //To read data from dataset
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            //Store the UserID
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void btn_run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int UserID;
            int TrackID;
            int counter=0;
            for (int ID = 1; ID <= 2916; ID++)
            {

                string url = "http://abcdef.com/ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<userid>?groups=<userid>";
                string test = test.Replace("i", Convert.ToString(UserID));
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
                string client = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://abcdef.com/ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<userid>?groups=<userid>");
                if (client.Contains(Convert.ToString(TrackID)))
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
int ave= counter/2916;
}
}
}
```

Comment: where is your script..??

Comment: i try to put my code but it shows error?????????

Comment: Are you asking how to verify some particular code you've wrote produces results you want?

Comment: somehow. I wrote it but it shows error.

Comment: What error does it show?  Did you *read* it?  What is your *question*??

Comment: use of unassigned local variable (variable test,UserID,TrackID)

Comment: All happens in `btn_run_Click`. Give some initial values to your variables, like `int UserID=0;` What is the initial value of *test* to make that replacement `string test = test.Replace("i", Convert.ToString(UserID));` **What is the value of `i+1` if you don't know the value of i?** :)

Comment: I did it and now shows "conn.open()" as an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do

```
var test = url.Replace("<userid>",Convert.ToString(UserID));
```

Is that not what your after?

Comment: Thank you.I did it and now shows "conn.open()" as an error.

Comment: is there anymore to the error? is your connection string wrong ?

Comment: it shows an error about connection string. but it must be correct.how can I check it?